# python syntax error invalid syntax

Tags: python

I'm new to Python programing language. I purchased a book and I've been reading it. The book is called (3x) Python Programming for the absolute beginner Third Edition. I'm trying to put what I've so far learned into action. I have a problem that I don't understand I know it's simple but I'm not sure how to solve it so if somebody can tell me what my the problem is and how to correct it. I appreciate it in advance! :) To add more I also tried doing it with python 2x and I had the same message error syntax, Invalid syntax.

[image: Python exercise]

Answer (score 2):

Whitespace is used to denote level of indention in Python.

The `else:` needs to be aligned (have the same indentation level) as the `if jim_age ...`.

```
if jim_age > sam_age:
    print("jim is older")
else:
    print("sam is older")
```

Comment: Also, the `else` body can't be empty (as you have shown in your example).

Comment: @TylerAndFriends I think the empty body is because the syntax error was spotted by the interpreter before it could be typed.

Comment: ahhhhhhhhh okay, I hadn't even thought of that.