# Python syntax error with "else"

Tags: syntax, syntax-error

I am using IDLE and Python 2.7. I am new to python and programming in general so sorry if this is extremely newbish, which it probably is.

Anyway, I'm following along and taking notes with python video and I was using IDLE and I keep getting this syntax error https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHcyP.png . I tried moving "else:" back to see if that was the problem but that didn't help. Just giving me a hint would help lol, thanks.

Comment: `else:` must line up exactly under the `if`.

Comment: I have tried that http://i.imgur.com/mXgBzrl.png

Comment: I see you're trying to enter that into an interactive Python shell. Normally the interactive shell is only convenient for entering and trying single-line statements, rather than writing whole programs. I recommend you step forward to where you are actually writing code in an editor, saving it in a file, and running the code using the normal Python runtime environment.

Comment: Well the vid I was watching was doing this just fine in the interactive shell so I was confused as why this wasn't working for me, I'll try it in an actual file and see if it work.

Comment: And wow, it works fine as an actual file but not in the Interactive Shell >.> FFS.. Thanks Greg lol.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python syntax error invalid syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19214053/python-syntax-error-invalid-syntax)

Answer (score 1):

White space is significant in loops and `if-else` in python, I believe you wanted something like

```
if sister_age > brother_age:
  print("Sister is older")
else:
  print("Brother is older")
```

Comment: Yeah that's what I want and I've entered it like that but it keeps giving me an error. Again see http://i.imgur.com/mXgBzrl.png I've tried various ways of indenting >.>

Answer (score 0):

I solve your problem and solution is very simple...you just have to start the else part from the start of IDLE like i have done you will get your desirable output .
[image: Output]